# Differential Equations 

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have solve this differential equation :

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}\frac{dy}{dx} + y &= f(x) \\
y (0)&=0.
\end{aligned}\right.$$ 
where $f (x) = \begin{cases}2 & \text{if } 0 \leq x < 1 \\
0 &\text{if }x \geq 1.\end{cases}$
Please explain how to solve as it involves discontinuous function $f$.

Comment: This is not an exact differential equation.  You'd need to multiply it by an integrating factor to get an exact differential equation.

Comment: The integrating factor does not involve the function on the right.  It would be the same integrating factor if the equation was $\frac{dy}{dx} + y = 0$.

Comment: @ Robert Israel: Thanks, I got the I.F as e ^x.

Comment: @Robert Israel : Please suggest how to proceed beyond this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply by the integrating factor $e^x$ and then you can *factor* the LHS: $$(e^xy)'=e^xf(x).$$ Now integrate from $0$ to $x$ to get $$e^xy(x)-e^0y(0)=\int_0^xe^uf(u)du$$ 
but remember $y(0)=0$. Now divide by the integrating factor and you have $y(x)=e^{-x}\int_0^xe^uf(u)du$. We can evaluate this by (a) looking at $x\in[0,1)$ and then (b) looking at $x\ge1$ for a piecewised defined solution $y$ (note: in the latter case you will have to split $\int_0^x$ into $\int_0^1+\int_1^x$ to substitute for $f$).